# Can't use canOpenUrl for InterApp communication

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, openurl

I would like to communicate between two Apps installed on the same phone. In order to do this, I read many official documents to understand that I have to implement a [Custom URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1).

Before iOS 9, it seems that we have to add a URLType in Info
and define the URL Scheme : "    ".

But after the iOS 9, it change the way to communicate between Apps.

The url scheme example is discussed in: [*Querying URL Schemes with canOpenURL*](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/).

My App A code below:

```
@IBAction func sender(sender: AnyObject) {

    let ourapplication : UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let ourpath : String = "iOSTest://"
        //.stringByAppendingString(urlEncodedText)
    let oururl : NSURL = NSURL(string: ourpath)!

    ourapplication.canOpenURL(oururl)
}
```

At My App B, I add a url name iOSTest in Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>iOSTest</string>
</array>
```

When I install the two App on my iPhone to test, it doesn't work at all.

Here is my error!

[image: Error photo]

What's wrong with my App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it setup incorrectly. The app calling `canOpenURL` is the app that needs to add the custom scheme to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` list.

Since App A is calling `canOpenURL` for `iIOSTest`, it is App A that needs to add `iOSTest` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` list, not App B.

App B would be the app that needs to register that it responds to `iOSTest` so that it will be opened when some other app calls `openURL` with a scheme of `iOSTest`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just swap both the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Comment: What are you asking? How to register the custom scheme with App B or what code you have to write in App B? Either way, that is an entirely different question. It is all covered in the docs and in many other questions here. This question should be closed since it has been solved. If you need assistance with the additional question, post another question specific to that issue.

Comment: What problem do you have now?

Comment: When I swap the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to App A, click the canOpenURL button still doesn't work. But when I change the canOpenURL to openUrl, it works!!!! I don't understand why canOpenURL doesn't work?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens? What message do you get?

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I finally figure out canOpenURL and openUrl.